# Merging of two libraries doesn't work in android ndk

Tags: build, android-ndk, static-libraries

I have a test app in Android NDK. Previously I was able to compile and run this app with provided static libs. The provided static lib was "libfulllib.a". Now I have written wrapper functions and made a lib of wrapper functions, i.e. "libwrapper.a". My working android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := rip_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/rip_test.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DCLR_INTERAPTIV_I7 -DCLR_INTERAPTIV -v
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include/hardware \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/inc \

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libsmem.sastra

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := \
    -v \
    -L$(ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT)/system/lib \
    -lsmem.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM) \
    -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/library \
    -lwrapper \
    -lfulllib \
    -llog \
    -lcutils \
    -lipc.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM) \

# this option will build executables instead of building library for
# android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Here the wrapper is a library made by me and full contain the real definitions of the functions. 
Now I don't want to expose fulllib to anyone, so I took out all the ".o" from wrapper and "fulllib." and made an 'all' library. Now my android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := rip_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/rip_test.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DCLR_INTERAPTIV_I7 -DCLR_INTERAPTIV -v
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include/hardware \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/inc \

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libsmem.sastra

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := \
    -v \
    -L$(ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT)/system/lib \
    -lsmem.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM) \
    -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/library \
    -lall \
    -llog \
    -lcutils \
    -lipc.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM) \

# this option will build executables instead of building library for
# android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I am able to compile, but the test app does not work the same. I want to ask:
is it safe to do this way?

What could be the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that might cause problems when merging two static libraries:

1. Duplicate symbols in either library.

   If both modules define a function `foo`, it is undefined which one will be used. This is true even without merging the libraries, but often the first symbol found is used, and if you repack the library such that the symbol in `fulllib` is now before `wrapper`, you might be using a different definition.
2. Multiple .o files with the same name.

   There are ways to do this safely, but depending on how you've created liball.a a foo.o in libfulllib.a might be overwriting one in libwrapper.a (or vice-versa).

This probably isn't an exhaustive list, but these are some of the problems I've encountered in the past.